# Why is StreamLocalBindUnlink disabled by default?

Tags: security, sshd, gpg-agent

I want to enable GPG agent forwarding, and found that `StreamLocalBindUnlink` is disabled by [default](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) on sshd.

Why is it disabled by default?

Is there any security risk in enabling it? Since X11 forwarding and agent forwarding are enabled by default, even though they include a security risk for the connecting user.